# Algorithm to draw sine wave on 2d grid

Tags: algorithm, hough-transform, bresenham

I have a 2D grid made of small rectangles that have a horizontal length `dx` and vertical `dy`. If I draw a sine wave on the grid, I want to identify all the rectangles for which this line goes through.

Are there any well known algorithms that I could look at? I haven't had much luck online. I am basically trying to do Bresenham's line algorithm, but for an arbitrary sine wave rather than a straight line.

I am doing all this in the context of a Hough transform, where my grid act as an accumulator that counts how many sine waves go through each rectangle.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the `sin` and `asin` functions from the math library?

Comment: Yes, I am actually writing this in Rust, but I didn't add any language tag.

Comment: Tesselate your curve and use the straight line Bresenham between the tesselation points. For better results approximate with a conic spline and use Bresenham's conic rasterisation algo. (But that's a lot of work unless you can find an off-the-shelf library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have curve equation for parameter `t` and want to find intersected "cells" - your small rectangles.

When current point is in some rectangle, it's borders are lines `x=k*dx, x=(k+1)*dx, y=m*dy, y=(m+1)*dy`, where `k,m` are  rectangle "coordinates".

You have to check what border will be intersected first (with smaller `t` parameter). For sine function it is not needed to check left border. So solve equations

```
 t1 = (k+1)*dx    
 sin(t2) = m*dy      => t2 = arcsin(m*dy)+ 2*Pi*n, Pi-arcsin(m*dy)+ 2*Pi*n 
 sin(t3) = (m+1)*dy
```

and choose smallest value from `(t1,t2,t3)` larger than current `t`. If `t1` is the smallest - you enter right cell, `k` increases. If `t2` is the smallest - you enter bottom cell, 'm' decreases, otherwise upper cell and `m` increases.

Now you have point of intersection with the next cell, new starting `t` and continue.

This approach is similar to  [Amanatides and Woo method](http://www.cse.yorku.ca/%7Eamana/research/grid.pdf) to select voxels being intersected by a ray/line.

Emm..OK, seems like overhead for the task of Hough transform, so subdividing into small line segments should work good enough.